# How to upload/download a file with Microsoft graph API in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, upload, microsoft-graph-api

I was able to make a oauth 2 login with Unity3d on Microsoft graph, I requested this permission for my app:
https://graph.microsoft.com/files.readwrite.appfolder

After the usual code flow (redirect to url, permission from user, auth code exchanged for token code and token for bearer auth code) I was able to log in.

Problem is that the upload of small files does not work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content

I think this is the best I can do:

```
string myData = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "provaupload.json");
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/AppTry/provaupload.json:/createUploadSession", myData)) {
        www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <code>");
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error + " " + www.downloadHandler.text);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Upload complete! " + www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
```

and I get this error:

```
Generic/unknown HTTP error {
  "error": {
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "id",
    "date": "2018-07-20T06:24:30"
  }
}
```

I also tried the WWW class or Put instead of Post but I get "invalid API".
Maybe my problem is in the base url:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

or maybe it's in the path
root:/AppTry/provaupload.json

or maybe in the permission.

I don't really know.

If you know how to make a Rest call with Microsoft Graph and One drive (even not in unity3d and even if you don't know how to solve my specific problem) it would be great to get some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload file, use the [`UploadHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UploadHandler.html). You must also encode the string as `UTF8`. As you mentioned in the comment section, it looks like you have to use `PUT` instead of `POST` and the url should be changed to something else.

Something more like this:

```
string myData = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "provaupload.json");
string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/AppTry/provaupload.json:/content";

using (UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(url, "PUT"))
{
    byte[] dataToSend = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(myData);
    www.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(dataToSend);
    www.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

    www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <code>");
    www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error + " " + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Upload complete! " + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try now also this solution. But right now I was able to make an upload by changing the scope to files.readwrite.all. I than used a Put with an array of byte. Anyway just a sec and I try also this answer.

Comment: Sure. Let me know. I put it to solve the "Unable to read JSON request payload" error

Comment: Your solution is not completly wrong. I tried it and I get Upload complete! but only it only create the folder. Still I was able to correct it with just 2 changes: instead of createUploadSession -> content and instead of POST -> PUT. Just correct those.

Comment: There is a difference between POST an PUT. You can't say *"completely wrong"* because this is the proper way to upload file with `UnityWebRequest` with `UploadHandler`. May there are other extra stuff to do to get that working but I on't have access to onedrive to test this. Glad you got it working with your way though.

Comment: Yes I know that there is a difference, but it's still working just by changing the POST to PUT. And createUploadSession  to content. And I think the reason is that https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_put_content microsoft only accept put for files upload

Comment: Ok, that makes sense in that case. Changing `UnityWebRequest(url, "POST"))` to `UnityWebRequest(url, "PUT"))` worked?

Comment: Yes. And also change the url from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/AppTry/provaupload.json:/createUploadSession to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/AppTry/provaupload.json:/content

Comment: Alright. Modified code to reflect that. You can always modify my answer if you think something is not right.