# WWW receive data in C# from php mysql in json format

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine, mamp

I am trying to read data from a mysql database hosted on mamp to display a players information in a unity scene. I can read and write to the database but I don't know how to display the information in unity at all. I read that you can use a json to format the data and then display that in unity but I don't know where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetPasswords : MonoBehaviour
{
string URL = "http://localhost:8888/sqlconnect/usergetpasswords.php";
public string[] usersData;

public void RetrievePasswords()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetPasswords());
}

IEnumerator DisplayPasswords()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("email", DBManager.email);
    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    yield return www;
    string usersDataString = www.text;
    usersData = usersDataString.Split(';');
    Debug.Log(usersData);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Start()
{
    RetrievePasswords();
}
```

}

**php script**

```
<?php

//place the relative position of the database such as https://www.000webhost.com/cpanel-login?from=panel.
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'unityaccess'); //replace root, root with your server username and password.


//Check that connection happened.
if (mysqli_connect_error())
{
//echo similar to debug, the message will populate the www.    
    echo "1: Connection failed"; //error code #1 = connection failed
    exit();
}

$email = $_POST["email"];

$sql = "SELECT email, account1, password1 FROM players WHERE email='" .$email . "';";


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo ("email: ".$row['email']."|account1: ".$row['account1']."|password1: ".$row['password1'].";");
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: I am trying to create a simple password manager, I can't read the information for each user from my mysql database and display it in a textbox in a unity scene. I want to get reading working before I add in AES encryption.

Comment: First of all: JSON in C#/Unity is possible, however, it can become a hard task. Is the JSON in a static, known format or can it be dynamic? If you do have the choice, I would consider to use other formats which are supported by Unity out of the box. I already did rape Unity to parse JSON since I had to adapt to a foreign API, and especially when JSON can vary dynamically, it is no fun at all and the library will bloat up the client app size.

Comment: I am not sure,  I have little experience using json. I have been stuck on this the last 2 days.

Comment: Why are you on JSON? Is there already any JSON you don't have influence to? You could even consider to write a Unity client/server app. Unity apps can run headless on server as well. *IF* you decide to try JSON, then use static structured objects represented by class declarations.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't actually do (and doesn't even try to do) any json at all. Why did you include that? What is the actual problem here?

Comment: There is no json in my code, that was a grammatical error on my side so I apologise. I am trying to read from a mysql database using php and then pass that data to a c# script so I can display the data in the scene to a user.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't give any hint on what data should be how downloaded and displayed ... Do you need help with the Unity part or with the php script? what exactly is not working / is your question?

Comment: I think that should make more sense now, basically I don't know how to read the data and format it in php so I can then display the appropriate data in unity.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetPasswords : MonoBehaviour
{

    string URL = "http://localhost:8888/sqlconnect/usergetpasswords.php";

    public void RetrievePasswords()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DisplayPasswords());
    }

    IEnumerator DisplayPasswords()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("email", DBManager.email);
        WWW www = new WWW(URL, form);
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("User Info = " + www.text);
    }

}
```

**php script**

```
<?php

    //place the relative position of the database such as https://www.000webhost.com/cpanel-login?from=panel.
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'unityaccess'); //replace root, root with your server username and password.


    //Check that connection happened.
    if (mysqli_connect_error())
    {
    //echo similar to debug, the message will populate the www.    
        echo "1: Connection failed"; //error code #1 = connection failed
        exit();
    }

    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $sql = "SELECT email, account1, password1 FROM players WHERE email='" .$email . "';";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo ("email: ".$row['email']."|account1: ".$row['account1']."|password1: ".$row['password1'].";");
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I was missing  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); from my php script, it's all g now. Onto the next problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You should not use WWW class anymore since it is obsolete
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

You should use UnityWebRequest instead
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html

You should also be able to replace WWWForm with IMultipartFormSection or byte[]

Right now I don't have any code with me, but I will be able to give you an example in 3 hours.

Still you can get an example right here:
[How to upload/download a file with Microsoft graph API in Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436399/how-to-upload-download-a-file-with-microsoft-graph-api-in-unity3d)

Note that I'm sure WWW class will be removed since I contacted Unity staff for the solution to replace it.